# How to sort numbers in excel that contains "/"

Tags: excel, vba

I have some numbers and some data in same row like this in excel

```
11        abc
12/2/2    def
13        ghi
12/2/1    jkl
12/1      mno
```

How can I sort it like this?

```
11       abc
12/1     mno
12/2/1   jkl
12/2/2   def
13       ghi
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it VBA or Excel? You tagged Excel only. Where is this values? On the sheet or in an array?

Comment: I would recommend normalizing your data if at all possible.  Even in VBA, this would be messy.

Comment: All these are in a sheet.

Answer (score 3):

You will require a 'helper' column that creates text from the 'numbers' without slashes. Sorting on these as text will provide the order you require. The 'helper' column can be deleted after its purpose has been fulfilled.

```
Sub Macro3()

    With Worksheets("sheet8")
        .Columns("A").Insert
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
            .Columns(1).Cells.FormulaR1C1 = "=substitute(rc[1], char(47), text(,))"
            .Sort key1:=.Cells(1), order1:=xlAscending, _
                  Header:=xlNo
        End With
        .Columns("A").Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the well wishes @Wizhi!